# Get list of tables but not include system tables (SQL Server 2K)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I know I can get a list of tables from a given database with the following query:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables
```

How do I go about excluding system tables though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select name from sysobjects where type='U'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as I expect it to.  One of the tables that show up under the System Tables folder in Management Studio, "dtproperties", also shows up in this query and my original.  How/why is Management Studio identifying it as a system table?

Comment: dtproperties stores the data diagram information I believe, I guess its technically classified as a user table.

Comment: Thanks.  So I guess I just write my query to specifically ignore that table or there a "cleaner" way around it?

Comment: If that's the only table giving you problems then I don't think it'd be too much of a coding horror to just write the query to specifically ignore it.

Comment: It is the only one at the moment, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't any other potential problems in the future.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but then again I wasn't aware that dtproperties was considered a user table either :)  I think that is the best that you can do though, the type flag is intended to be used for differentiating between system and user but this is a special case where a management studio designer is generating a table so from MSSQL's perspective its not a system table, as I understand it.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is quite an old question, but someone's just edited it to resurrect it, and the "right" answer from my perspective isn't either of the two listed. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216283/15498) includes some "system" tables (`dtproperties` is mentioned in the comments. If the user had any replication going on, they'd have found a few more).

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216703/15498) uses a 2005 table, but is so nearly correct. For 2000, you want to use [`OBJECTPROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276849%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) instead:

```
select name from sysobjects where
    OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsTable')=1 and
    OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsMSShipped')=0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name FROM [database].sys.tables where is_ms_shipped=0
```

Comment: Sorry, sys.tables is not supported in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'sys%'
```

Not an elegant solution but this was my quick way to exclude dbo.sysdiagrams, which was the only system table in my list.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question too, but you can execute the sql server stored procedure :

> EXEC sp_tables @table_name="%", @table_owner="%",@table_type="'TABLE'"

and retrieve your table list. But is not supported with SQL 2K. Exists since the 2005 server...