# How to check if SQL Server Tables are System Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Using the stored procedure `sp_msforeachtable` it's possible to execute a script for all tables in a database.

However, there are system tables which I'd like to exclude from that. Instinctively, I would check the properties `IsSystemTable` or `IsMSShipped`. These don't work like I expect - I have for example a table called `__RefactorLog`:

[image: System table]

But when I query if this is a system or MS Shipped table, SQL Server reports none of my tables are system tables:

```
exec (N'EXEC Database..sp_msforeachtable "PRINT ''? = '' + CAST(ObjectProperty(Object_ID(''?''), ''IsSystemTable'') AS VARCHAR(MAX))"') AS LOGIN = 'MyETLUser'
-- Results of IsSystemTable:
[dbo].[__RefactorLog] = 0
[schema].[myUserTable] = 0
```

and

```
exec (N'EXEC Database..sp_msforeachtable "PRINT ''? = '' + CAST(ObjectProperty(Object_ID(''?''), ''IsMSShipped'') AS VARCHAR(MAX))"') AS LOGIN = 'MyETLUser'

-- Results of IsMSShipped:
[dbo].[__RefactorLog] = 0
[schema].[myUserTable] = 0
```

When I look into the properties of the table (inside SSMS), the table is marked as a system object. An object property like `IsSystemObject` doesn't exist though (AFAIK).

How do I check if a table is a system object, apart from the object property? How does SSMS check if a table is a system object?

Comment: Although this question looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216219/get-list-of-tables-but-not-include-system-tables-sql-server-2k, it isn't duplicate as the ways of checking object properties has changed since SQL Server 2000 and I'm asking the way SSMS checks it.

Comment: You could always run SQL Server profiler against your server when opening the "System Tables" folder, and see what SQL it's running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Management studio 2008 seems to run some quite ugly following code when opening the "System Tables" folder in the object explorer, the key bit seems to be:

```
CAST(
 case 
    when tbl.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = tbl.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N''microsoft_database_tools_support'') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject]
```

(Where `tbl` is an alias for `sys.tables`)

So it seems that it's a combination - either `is_ms_shipped` from `sys.tables` being 1, or having a particular extended property set.

Answer (score 2):

__refactorlog is, in contrast to what SSMS suggests, a user table. It is used during deployment to track schema changes that cannot be deduced from the current database state, for example renaming a table.

If all your other user tables are in a custom (non-dbo) schema, you can use a combination of the isMSshipped/isSystemTable attributes and the schema name to decide if a table is 'in scope' for your script.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've worked on the assumption that, in the sys.objects table, column is_ms_shipped indicates whether an object is or is not a system object. (This column gets inherited by other system tables, such as sys.tables.)

This flag can be set by procedure sp_ms_markSystemObject. This, however, is an undocumented procedure, is not supported by Microsoft, I don't think we're supposed to know about it, so I didn't tell you about it.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

> However, there are system tables which I'd like to exclude from that

At least on SQL Server 2008, `sp_MSforeachtable` **already** excludes system tables, as this excerpt from it shows:

```
+ N' where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N''IsUserTable'') = 1 ' + N' and o.category & ' + @mscat + N' = 0 '
```

Comment: I don't know if you're missing something, but when I execute the given queries while logged in as my ETL user, the query also tries to process the __RefactorLog table (which SSMS designates as a 'System Object')

Comment: Once upon a time, I stumbled across the fact that Enterprise Manager (SQL 2000) was hard-coded to treat some tables as system tables, though SQL itself did not flag them as such. (This was the diagram tables.) They might still be doing tricks like this in SSMS...